# How to apply assets to different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I bought two themes from https://wrapbootstrap.com/

I put the first theme under assets/index_theme

So I added `//= require_tree ../theme/js` in `.//assets/javascripts/application.js`
and add file `.//app/assets/lenord-single-page-theme/js/application.js`

`.//app/assets/lenord-single-page-theme/js/application.js`

```
//= require_tree .
```

and did the same thing for css.

But it applied to all pages in whole websites

I only want to apply it on a specific controller's view only for index

And Applied another theme to others controllers' views

How could I achieve it ?

```
.
├── images
├── javascripts
├── stylesheets
└── lenord-single-page-theme
    ├── css
    ├── fonts
    ├── img
    │   ├── portfolio
    │   ├── prettyPhoto
    │   │   ├── dark_rounded
    │   │   ├── dark_square
    │   │   ├── default
    │   │   ├── facebook
    │   │   ├── light_rounded
    │   │   └── light_square
    │   └── service
    ├── js
    └── rs-assets
```

Comment: +1 for tree structure diagram!!

Answer (score 1):

In your application.html.erb file:

```
<% if params[:controller] == 'your_controller_name' %>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'index_theme.css' %>
< %end %>
```

If you need even more control and only want specific actions:

```
<% if params[:controller] == 'your_controller_name' && params[:action] == 'your_action_name' %>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'index_theme.css' %>
< %end %>
```

If you are trying to conrol javascript files instead of css:

```
<% if params[:controller] == 'your_controller_name' && params[:action] == 'your_action_name' %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/index_theme.js" %>
< %end %>
```

notice the js tag includes /assets/ and the css tag does not.

Comment: Did your solution can include all the js , css files under their folder ?